# CMAKE view possible options

Tags: cmake

The CMake option command allows users to define variable from command line:

```
option(<option_variable> "help string describing option"
     [initial value])
```

I am wondering how to view all such available options.  I.e. I am looking for something like `./configure -h` where it typically shows a summary all possible configuration a user can tweak.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all CMake build options and their default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851084/how-to-list-all-cmake-build-options-and-their-default-values)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature for a simple reason - command [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html) is not always evaluated. E.g.:

```
if(WIN32)
  option(WIN32_TESTS "Build windows specific tests" OFF)
endif()
```

So you need to run cmake anyway, then you can view options in `CMakeCache.txt` file directly or
using cmake-gui (or ccmake).

Of course you can print the messages manually:

```
message("Build configuration:")
message("  C++ flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
if(WIN32)
  message("  WIN32_TESTS: ${WIN32_TESTS}")
endif()
```