# Prevent cmake from allowing any value for CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES

Tags: cmake

I am trying to do something like

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Debug;RelWithDebInfo" ...
```

I wanted to check if I did not have any mistakes in type names so I tried something nonsensical hoping cmake will error out and confirm that my configuration types are correct.

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Debug;Relalaland" ...
```

But cmake just creates the configuration types I specify...

[image]

Is there a way to tell cmake to not accept unfamiliar CONFIGURATION_TYPES?

Comment: ? So just in pseudocode `if (CONFIGURATION_TYPES not in some_list_of_allowed_types) error() endif()` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk what I mean is that cmake AFAIK has some predefined types, I want to be able to only specify those... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754619/what-are-cmake-build-type-debug-release-relwithdebinfo-and-minsizerel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell cmake to not accept unfamiliar CONFIGURATION_TYPES?

**Don't.** A user might want to define a custom configuration type externally, which is perfectly possible to do in a toolchain file or at the command line. One use for this might be for sanitizer builds. In general, you should avoid restricting what your users can do with your build. Only *hard requirements* go in your CMakeLists.txt and denying a custom build type doesn't qualify.

All that said, here's how you can do this:

```
set(known_types Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel)
get_property(is_multi_config GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
if (is_multi_config)
  foreach (config IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    if (NOT config IN_LIST known_types)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Build type '${config}' invalid. Expected one of: ${known_types}")
    endif ()
  endforeach ()
elseif (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE IN_LIST known_types)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build type '${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}' invalid. Expected one of: ${known_types}")
endif ()
```

This works for both single and multi config generators.

Comment: my cmake commands code will never be shared, and my code will never be used as part of some larger projects so for me limiting is fine...  and users are people that know to change the cmake if they need too... so not a big problem for me...  but great answer.

Comment: From my understanding, possible set of build types is controlled by the **project**, not by a user. A user could only set variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` to the **reduced** set of build types. This could be useful e.g. when one want to install or pack only release variant of the project. E.g. in the [CMake FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-specify-my-own-configurations-for-generators-that-allow-it-) they suggest to set variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` using CACHE ... FORCE, which would ignore a value set by a user.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - The CMake FAQ hasn't been meaningfully updated in years... it's a _very poor_ source of information pertaining to CMake 3.x+. Look around a bit more... it still says precompiled headers aren't supported!

Answer (score 2):

So just check them.

```
set(allowed_types Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel)
foreach(i IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
   if(NOT i IN_LIST allowed_types)
       message(FATAL_ERROR "${i} is not valie configuration type")
   endif()
endforeach()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for single-config generators (see my answer).