# Make CMake generate only Release and Debug configurations

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

Is it possible to make CMake generate only `Release` and `Debug` configurations and make `Release` configuration to be `RelWithDebInfo`?

The problem is that QT Creator understands only `Release` and `Debug` and do not understand `RelWithDebInfo`, see https://forum.qt.io/topic/144983/qt-6-5-signs-debug-package for more information.

[image]

Comment: @Friedrich the compiler is Android CLang, what is `-g`?

Comment: So you can't set [`CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.html) to `RelWithDebInfo;Debug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate debug symbols in clang, call it with the [-g option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-g).

The most simple solution would be to add a line to your top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(-g)
```

[`Add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) will unconditionally set the option for all targets in this directory and those below. It will do so for all configurations (it should already be set in debug and will do no harm if set twice).

To have more control for which targets and configurations to generate debug info, use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) with a generator expression like the following:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Release>:-g>)
```

This will work with GCC and clang but not with other compilers that use different options (most notably MSVC).

Comment: looks like I also need to replace `-O3` with `-O2`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754619/what-are-cmake-build-type-debug-release-relwithdebinfo-and-minsizerel

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish. If you want to have debug information, `-g` is enough. If you also want to have less optimization, then you need to change to `-O2`. Looking at differences between `-O2` and `-O3` in the [clang doc](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-o0), I wouldn't bother.