# What command in Equivalent of ./configure --help in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I want to show options of cmake.
I was using `cmake --help-variables` but it is too long and includes non-package specific options.

I would like to show cmake options that package specific only.
How do I do it?

Comment: You have definitely checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851084/how-to-list-all-cmake-build-options-and-their-default-values), haven't you?

Comment: Thanks for reply! `cmake -LAH` very good!